# Where are all of the Sokolov paintings for "Art Dealer"?

Tags: dishonored

There is an achievement for collecting all of the Sokolov paintings. What are all of their locations, and what do they even look like?

[image: Art Dealer]

#### Art Dealer

> Collect all the Sokolov paintings

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Mission 02](http://youtu.be/QloXKJUdpB8?t=4s): **High Overseer Campbell**

- 1 of 1 - 'The Isometry of High Overseer Thaddeus Campbell'

  - The painting is located in Campbell's Secret Chambers, which can be opened by activating the eye of the statue next to it. You can find the Chamber from the video, which starts in the room where you can decide to spike their wine with poison.

[Mission 03](http://youtu.be/QloXKJUdpB8?t=54s): **House of Pleasure**

- 1 of 3 - 'Light Along the Inverse Curve, Sokolov's Self Portrait'
- 2 of 3 - 'Daud and the Parabola of the last Seasons'
- 3 of 3 - 'Custis, Morgan and the Postulate Child'

  - You can find all 3 paintings in the Art Dealers building. You can get to it as shown in the video, or you can get a key from a Survivor who needs help in the Gaff Street Alley (left side). The 3rd painting requires a combo, which you can get from the Art Dealer himself at the 'The Cat'. For me, it was 1-8-3.

[Mission 04](http://youtu.be/QloXKJUdpB8?t=2m34s): **The Royal Physician**

- 1 of 1 - 'The Obtuse Arguments of Lady Boyle'

  - Can be found in the first floor of Sokolov's House.

[Mission 05](http://youtu.be/QloXKJUdpB8?t=3m03s): **Lady Boyle's Last Party**

- 1 of 2 - 'Vera Moray and the Affix of Her Skin'
- 2 of 2 - 'The Spymaster's Axis of Asymmetry'

  - Both paintings can be found in the Lady Boyle's mansion. The video begins the path to finding them from the central Foyer. Make sure you turn off the Wall of Light for the first (or find another path to the 2nd floor). The second painting can be found in Lady Boyle's room, which is normally guarded by a Watch Officer.

[Mission 06](http://youtu.be/QloXKJUdpB8?t=4m16s): **Return to the Tower**

- 1 of 1 - 'The Empress and the Empty Set'

  - Once you reach the Tower Interior, Blink up to the 2nd Floor. You'll find it on the room on the left.

[Mission 07](http://youtu.be/QloXKJUdpB8?t=4m51s): **The Flooded District**

- 1 of 3 - 'The Commutative Rats and the Weeper'
- 2 of 3 - 'The Torturer's Quaternionic Groan'
- 3 of 3 - 'The Outsider and the Circumstanced Void'

  - First painting is right after you make your escape, but before heading for your gear (or Daud's House). Blink to the high catwalk that has a overhanging mattress. The second painting is found after you encounter Daud. Once you leave the area, look for the painting as you are going down the chain. The final painting is in Granny Rags room, right above her bed.

[This was all from this fine gentleman's YouTube video.](http://youtu.be/QloXKJUdpB8)

As for what the paintings themselves look like, well... They're fairly hard to miss. They are full sized paintings complete with frames, but the artwork on them varies; for example, a woman facing away from the viewer, a man sitting in a chair, or a man standing with his arms at his side.

Comment: was looking for the guide as well, thanks for the breakdown +1