# Do I have to earn the Art Dealer achievement in a single playthrough?

Tags: achievements, dishonored

I've just finished the (great) game, and I think I only missed two of the [Sokolov paintings](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/87233/where-are-all-of-the-sokolov-paintings-for-art-dealer).  I'm also pretty sure to know the chapter where I missed them; can I simply reload this chapter and collect the missing ones, or should I replay the entire game ?

Comment: i have just gone through the missions collecting them all...and no achievement... im fuming! i think it might need to be done in a single play through! im not happy! but then again...i playing through it all again for another achievement so will hopefully get it done...or it might get patched!
good luck

Comment: @desaivv He did post it as an answer. It was converted to a comment, because no, it does not seem to clearly answer the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, so after several tests, it appears that **yes**, this achievement has to be earned in a single playthrough.

Also, I had a little problem with [Granny Rags](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Vera_Moray): during my second playthrough to get all the paintings, I ran as fast as possible, skipping almost all the side quests, including Granny Rags ones.  It prevented me from getting [the last painting ("The Outsider and the Circumstanced Void")](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/File:The_Outsider_and_the_Circumscribed_Void.png).  As a matter a fact, when you skip her quests, you cannot access [one of the last areas](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/File:GR_and_SJ.jpg) where you can either fight her or help her to kill [Slackjaw](http://dishonored.wikia.com/wiki/Slackjaw) but also access her room where you'll find the painting.  So that's something you'll have to keep in mind if you start a playthrough dedicated to the paintings.

[image]